# iPhone 4 (iPhone3,1) reboots while exploiting limera1n

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, downgrade

Please help.
I'm currently trying to downgrade my iPhone 4 (running iOS 7.1.2) to iOS 7.0.4 (or a version of iOS 6, I'm not sure yet). However, whenever I use iREB or redsn0w (via limera1n exploit) to enter a pwned DFU state, the device disconnects and reboots. This occurs once the exploit progressbar reaches 100%.

Can this be downgraded so that I can jailbreak with evasi0n7?

Answer (score 1):

You have a catch 22.

- You need to jailbreak to downgrade.
- A downgrade is needed to jailbreak.